# Share Windows Credentials across multiple Windows Store Apps (Win 10)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Details:

- Target version: Windows 10 1803
- Min version: Windows 10 Creators Update
- nuget: Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.1.5

I have two sample Uwp apps. Both has use fallowing method:

```
private string GetPasswordCredential()
{
    PasswordVault passwordVault = new PasswordVault();
    PasswordCredential passwordCredential = null;

    try
    {
        var passwordCredentials = new List<PasswordCredential>(passwordVault.RetrieveAll());
        if (passwordCredentials.Any(c => c.Resource.Equals("testResource") && c.UserName.Equals("testUserName")))
        {
            passwordCredential = passwordVault.Retrieve(resource: "testResource", userName: "testUserName");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        var message = exception.Message;
    }

    if (passwordCredential == null)
    {
        // create credential deteils
        passwordCredential = new PasswordCredential(resource: "testResource", userName: "testUserName", password: "testPassword");

        // add credential details to password vault
        passwordVault.Add(passwordCredential);
    }

    return passwordCredential.Password;
}
```

The problem is that, the method creates unique Credentials for every app:
[image]

My aim is to create one Credential detail if not exists, and use it by second App as well once second App gets run. The above method logic does a check but also create brand new Credential for each App. Only difference I can see 'Saved By' section. 
How can I force second App to grab/use already existed Credential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I force second App to grab/use already existed Credential?

You can't. The [offical documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault) is pretty clear on the fact that "the contents of the locker [represented by the `PasswordVault` class] are specific to the app or service. Apps and services don't have access to credentials associated with other apps or services.".

So `App2` cannot access a credential created by `App1` and vice versa. This is by design.

Comment: I marked your comments as an answer. However, Do you know any alternative for it? I don't want to use Brokered WinRT Component approach  though.

Comment: If you want to share data between different apps, you can't use the `PasswordVault` class. You'd better store the shared data in some remote place like for example a database or a file share in Azure.

Comment: I have to share data within local device memory for off-line scenario across multiple uwp apps(Apps come from same Publisher).

Comment: Store the data in some share local folder then.

Comment: "I don't want to use Brokered WinRT Component approach though." @mazury, I see this in your comment for this answer. I would like to try this approach. Could you please give me some directions to access UWP app's password vault from the component